# How to get the size of a collection without loading the full collection in Magento 2

Tags: collection, count

I need to check the number of items in a collection without loading the full collection (as it has over 1.5 million items and causes memory issues).

Is there an efficient way to go about this?

Comment: Going threw raw count sql may be if it's juste to get a value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getSize() method for this.

**Usage:** `$collection->getSize();`

**getSize()** method execute a count SQL query into the database and give you the count.

You can read in detail by below article.

https://webkul.com/blog/optimizing-magento-magento2-part-1/